# How to avoid adding time to date in Pandas to Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, dataframe

So I have excel file with data where some headers are text and over are dates like 19.07.2023 etc:

```
Item/Date   19.07.2023  20.07.2023  21.07.2023
Some Item      58               51             57
```

When I importing this file to pandas it's looks like this:
[image]

After that I just do some merging with over excel file to get new column with latest date and exporting back to excel and my date of 19.07.2023 is 2023-07-19 0:00:00 now. How to avoid adding not needed time and also avoid changing format to d-m-Y? A can specify in excel after that this is Date and format will be changet to corrct one, but I want to avoid additional steps in the process.

[image]

Code example

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
test2_df = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsb')
test_total = test_df.merge(test2_df, how='outer').fillna(0)
test_total.to_excel('file_total.xlsx', index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the dates and do not want time in `YYYY-MM-DD` format :

```
df['Your_Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Your_Column']).dt.date
```

This will just give you dates. But, the datatype will be `'object'`.

---

as @D.L stated this should also work:

```
df['Your_Column'] = df['Your_Column'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But, the datatype will be `'object'`.

---

```
df['Your_Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Your_Column']).dt.normalize()
```

can change the datatype of your column to `'datetime64'`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a bit harder because the values that you want to amend is in the column headers and not the rows of data, but i managed to do it like this.

- using the `datetime` module to convert the dates into the required format.
- looping thought the columns to amend each header (apart from the first column)

so the code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

file = 'tests/test_excel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)


remane_dict = {}
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    col:dt.datetime
    remane_dict[col] = col.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(remane_dict)
df.rename(columns=remane_dict ,inplace=True)

print(df)
```

the input data from an excel looks like this:

```
  Item / date  2023-07-19 00:00:00  2023-07-20 00:00:00  2023-07-21 00:00:00
0   some item                   58                   51                   57
```

and the result looks like this:

```
  Item / date  2023-07-19  2023-07-20  2023-07-21
0   some item          58          51          57
```

You would need to apply to each dataframe that you are working on that has this format. Then you can merge or do whatever you like with the correct headers in place.